# Fiddler traffic shows 404 error website still loads

Tags: https, http-status-code-404, fiddler

I am somewhat of a novice at debugging web traffic, so I am simply trying to understand what is going on.

I have fiddler and am using it to look at the network traffic being sent as I navigate to a specific website.  I am noticing that the traffic picks up an HTTP 404 error thrown but I am still able to load the website.

Please help me understand how it still loads the website when it throws an HTTP 404 error?  The error is never shown to the user.  It is like it is ignoring it.  I would think it would display the error to user and never load the website.

I have attached a picture of what I am seeing in Fiddler.

thanks

[FiddlerTrafficwith404error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6axJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for this behavior is the browser stores the page in cache that is already loaded in browser once. Try opening the page in incognito/private mode (depending upon what your browser calls it) or try clearing your browser's cache and history.

Comment: Hi,

could you elaborate on how this could result in a 404? I am experiencing the same issue as the Questioneer, and I am a bit at a loss.